# Unable to delete entry from table where value contains a space in the middle?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm able to delete the entries which have a single word like 'Tomato' or 'Potato'.
Unable to delete entries with multiple words like 'pumpkin soup'.

Why is that?

Here's my PHP:

```
<?php
                   if(!empty($_POST['event_name_box']))
                   {
                    $del_event=$_POST['event_name_box'];
                    $sth = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM event WHERE event_name=:del");
                    $sth->execute(array(':del'=>$del_event));
                    header( "Refresh: 0;" );
                   }
            ?>
```

And this is how I'm loading the values in drop down:

```
 <select name="event_name_box" value="event_name_box" style="width:220px; padding-left:40px;font-size:18px;font-family:Roboto;">
            <?php
            $sth = $conn->prepare('Select event_name From event');
            $sth->execute();
            $data = $sth->fetchAll();   
            foreach ($data as $row ){
                if($row['event_name']!="")
            echo " <option id=\"EventName\" name=\"EventName\" value=".$row['event_name'].">".$row['event_name']."</option>";
            }
            ?> 
            </select><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" style="width:50%;padding:10px" value="Delete"</input>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your HTML (specifically, the `<option>` tag). Your value isn't quoted, so the space is breaking the value sent in the POST. Change the echo on your option to something like this:

```
echo '<option value="' . $row['event_name'] . '">' . $row['event_name'] . '</option>';
```

(You also shouldn't need the `name` and `id` on your `<option>` tags.)

Answer (score 0):

You are not quoting the `value` content in your `<option` tag, so it won't be interpreted correctly by the browser.

A simple trace in your PHP script should have made it obvious that it does not receive the proper content.